# OpenShift permission issues to expose registry

Tags: openshift, okd

I am trying to expose the docker-registry using the below command:

```
# oc expose service docker-registry --hostname=<hostname> -n default
```

Source: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/install_config/registry/securing_and_exposing_registry.html#access-insecure-registry-by-exposing-route

However, I get permission issues with "forbidden" messages in the output for the current user I login with. The user has "admin" rights. I am new to OpenShift and still learning. Can someone point me in the right direction for how to expose registry service using the above command? It looks like I might need "cluster-admin" access permission in order to perform this operation but not sure how to change or add role to the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `admin` role is for what project ? Basically, `admin` role is granted permission for one project.
As you mentioned above, you need to `cluster-admin` cluster role in order to create route using `oc expose service` in `default` project. Or you are required `admin` role of `default` project. Each command is as follows for granting each role.

You also are required `cluster-admin` role to run the following both commands.

```
// for instance, the following command is granting cluster-admin role to admin.
$ oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin admin

// following command is granting admin of default project role to admin.
$ oc adm policy add-role-to-user admin admin -n default
```

If you can login as `system:admin` after access master host via ssh as root, you can get `cluster-admin` role.

```
# oc login -u system:admin --config /etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig
```

I hope it help you.